# Real time bidding script

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create a bidding website just like this, http://www.quibids.com/
What is the best way how to handle the real time bidding system? Any tips?

Eg. When clicking the BID button, how to make it real time to the other users that are being outbid?

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered in its current form.

Answer (score 1):

The best method would be to keep polling the server to see if the currently logged in user has the highest bid, if they do, great, otherwise, make it red and perhaps do some flashy animation to let the user know.

I think that's what you mean anyway, it's a fairly simple concept that can be done with a simple repeating GET request.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna save bandwidth and CPU time, you might want a publisher/subscriber system rather than polling at short intervals, however unless you think all of your users will have a browser implementing websockets you'll have to use some plugin if you wan the server to be able to really push events to the clients.